# window service should interact with UI

Tags: windows-services

I have a Windows service which launches GUI on startup on Win 2003 OS. But due to security feature introduced in win 2008 (Session 0 Isolation) my window service is not able to launch GUI. How can i achieve to launch GUI by window service on win 2008 platform.

Note : I don't want to enable "Interactive Service Detection" to achieve the solution.
Pls let me know if anyone has faced or implemented mentioned problem.

I have created sample service , where i am putting below code in OnStart function.
Hi Seva, i went through your comments and made a sample windows service.I am putting below code in OnStart. Service is getting started but it is not showing the "notepad.exe". Can you suggest if i am doing anything wrong here.

```
HANDLE hToken    = NULL;
HANDLE hTokenDup = NULL;
STARTUPINFO si;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
ZeroMemory( &si, sizeof( STARTUPINFO ) );
ZeroMemory( &pi, sizeof( PROCESS_INFORMATION ) );

si.cb = sizeof( STARTUPINFO );
si.lpDesktop = _T("Winsta0\\Default");

DWORD  dwCreationFlag = NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS | CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE;
LPVOID pEnvironment = NULL;
LPFNCREATEENVIRONMENTBLOCK  lpfnCreateEnvironmentBlock  = NULL;
LPFNDESTROYENVIRONMENTBLOCK lpfnDestroyEnvironmentBlock = NULL;
HMODULE hUserEnvLib = NULL;
hUserEnvLib = LoadLibrary( _T("userenv.dll") );
if ( NULL != hUserEnvLib ) {
    lpfnCreateEnvironmentBlock  = (LPFNCREATEENVIRONMENTBLOCK)
    GetProcAddress( hUserEnvLib, "CreateEnvironmentBlock" );

    lpfnDestroyEnvironmentBlock = (LPFNDESTROYENVIRONMENTBLOCK)
    GetProcAddress( hUserEnvLib, "DestroyEnvironmentBlock" );
}
OpenThreadToken( GetCurrentThread(), TOKEN_DUPLICATE, TRUE, &hToken );
DuplicateTokenEx( hToken,
                  TOKEN_IMPERSONATE|TOKEN_READ|TOKEN_ASSIGN_PRIMARY|TOKEN_DUPLICATE,
                  NULL, SecurityImpersonation, TokenPrimary, &hTokenDup );
RevertToSelf( );
CloseHandle( hToken );
if ( NULL != lpfnCreateEnvironmentBlock ) {
    if ( lpfnCreateEnvironmentBlock( &pEnvironment, hTokenDup, FALSE ) ) {
        dwCreationFlag |= CREATE_UNICODE_ENVIRONMENT;   // must specify
    }
    else {
        pEnvironment = NULL;
        OutputDebugString( _T(" CreateEnvironmentBlock() -- FAILED") );
    }
}
else {
    OutputDebugString(_T(" FAILED - GetProcAddress(CreateEnvironmentBlock)"));
}
CreateProcessAsUser( hTokenDup, NULL, _T("C:\\windows\\system32\\notepad.exe"),
                     NULL, NULL, FALSE, dwCreationFlag,
                     pEnvironment, NULL, &si, &pi );
if ( NULL != lpfnDestroyEnvironmentBlock )
    lpfnDestroyEnvironmentBlock( pEnvironment );
if ( NULL != hUserEnvLib ) FreeLibrary( hUserEnvLib );
CloseHandle( hTokenDup );
```

Above code seems not working, anyone can help me out to resolve this issue?
-Dev

Comment: You may want to re-think your architecture a bit.  I have built apps where the UI interfaces with a Windows Service.  But I've never started a user process from a service process.  Can you explain your specific use case in a bit more detail?

Answer (score 0):

Recommended ways for dealing with session isolation are described in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683502%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You have two options:

1. A simple but very limited way is just displaying dialog boxes in user session using WTSSendMessage API.
2. More difficult, but much more flexible option is having a separate process that runs in user session (and attached to user desktop). Your service communicates to that process using some sort of IPC mechanism.

For #2 there are few methods how you can launch a process in user session. A popular approach is hooking up to [At Logon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc507860.aspx) trigger. Another approach is using [CreateProcessAsUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You can look up sample code for using it to launch process in different session [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssecurity/thread/31bfa13d-982b-4b1a-bff3-2761ade5214f/).

Comment: Hi Seva, i went through your comments and made a sample windows service.I am putting below code in OnStart. Service is getting started but it is not showing the "notepad.exe". Can you suggest if i am doing anything wrong here.

Comment: Hi Seva, I have put my sample code in my question. (I have edited question). Do you find the code proper, or m i doing any mistake?

Comment: That is a different question. Please try to ask one question at a time at StackOverflow, otherwise people get confused which question they are supposed to answer.